# upload videos in Youtube through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

I would like to upload videos to Youtube through an HTTP Web Request.

I do not  want to use any DLL provided by YouTube.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not showing any effort to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try hitting their API directly. I'm not sure why you don't want to use their dll but it would be easiest to use them.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{  
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/insert", video);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Casey, i will try this.